# Search API development with refiner language column

Tags: development, rest, refiner, search-api

I'm currently working on a search driven App in SharePoint 2013 based on JavaScript and some forms.

The mission is to get results from the search refinery in real-time for a specific search term. To realize this i used the search rest api to get all refinery options for a special refiner.

In my special case I ask the search api to get all possible language values for the refiner language (global language column) back to work with them. That works but i only get back the abbreviations for the languages like en, de, nl etc.

But what i need is the full name back like: English, German, Dutch.

Is there any option to get this values back from the search api, or any other place in SharePoint to match this values to a name? I don't found anythink in the API.

If you need more details or code snippets, please let me know.

Thanks for your help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint stores the language using the [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) codes.  You can create an object or enum to store these codes with their language values.  For a list of all the codes, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) link.

Comment: Thanks, i also found this. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristopherloranger/archive/2012/01/30/how-does-fast-sharepoint-handle-the-language-refiner.aspx